# SQL error ORA-00979 Group By error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

So the question asks me that:
"What is the average cost of service visits on 2009 Mercedes?"
I am therefore joining two tables: ServInv and Car, to get the result but keep getting an error:

```
SELECT car.make, car.model, servinv.totalcost, AVG(servinv.totalcost)
FROM s2.servinv 
INNER JOIN s2.car 
ON servinv.cname = car.cname 
WHERE car.make = 'MERCEDES'
AND car.cyear = '2009'
GROUP BY servinv.totalcost
;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
select * from s2.car;
```

This gives the following:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8svQ.png

And:

```
select * from s2.servinv;
```

Gives the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYmm5.png

As for the description of the tables, the Car table looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py80K.png

And the Servinv table is as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjPuL.png

Comment: Be a pal, and edit your post with your table definitions and some sample data from the tables. Thank you!

Comment: Done! Is this enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your dimensions such as make and model in group by. Include statistics with your numeric fields.

```
SELECT car.make, car.model, SUM(servinv.totalcost), AVG(servinv.totalcost)
FROM s2.servinv 
INNER JOIN s2.car 
ON servinv.cname = car.cname 
WHERE car.make = 'MERCEDES'
AND car.cyear = '2009'
GROUP BY car.make, car.model;
```

This way, we tell the DB to give us totalcost (total of totalcost and average of the total) from all records of 2009 Mercedes.